# Are delegates copied during assignment to an event?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

The following code seems to execute the FileRetrieved event more than once. I thought delegates were a reference type. I was expecting this to execute once. I'm going to take a guess and say that the reference is being passed by value, therefore copied but I don't like guesswork :-)

```
public delegate void DirListEvent<T>(T dirItem);

void Main()
{
    DirListEvent<string> printFilename = s => {
        Console.WriteLine (s);
    };

    var obj = new DirectoryLister();

    obj.FileRetrieved += printFilename;
    obj.FileRetrieved += printFilename;

    obj.GetDirListing();
}

public class DirectoryLister {

    public event DirListEvent<string> FileRetrieved;


    public DirectoryLister() {
        FileRetrieved += delegate {};
    }

    public void GetDirListing() {

        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\"))
        {
            FileRetrieved(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't see how "delegates are a reference type" should in any way connect to "being executed once". You've registered the same delegate twice with the event handler, hence it's been called twice - why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, **every delegate instance comes with an invocation list**, which is essentially just a list of all the references to the target events that you associate with. For instance,

```
public event DirListEvent<string> FileRetrieved;
```

the code above creates a delegate type called FileRetrieved (as you already know).
This delegate type now has an invocation list that keeps all the delegate instances that you register using += operator or Delegate.Combine method.

```
obj.FileRetrieved += printFilename;
obj.FileRetrieved += printFilename;
```

This code basically adds 2 of the same delegate instances to the FileRetrieved invocation list. **The invocation list allows duplicate instances.** Hence, when FileRetrieved is invoked, it goes through its invocation list and finds that there are 2 methods added (both printFilename) and just delegate the calls to printFilename as it supposed to do.

Try having another line of `obj.FileRetrieved += printFilename;` and FileRetrieved should invoke printFilename 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, FileRetrieved is a collection of delegates, and the same delegate can appear in this collection multiple times.  Not all collections are sets ...

Comment: Correct, `obj.FileRetrieved` ends up containing multiple references to the same delegate.